# How to configure a Webhook in Azure DevOps and integrate it with Power Automate to enable interaction/connection?

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, power-automate

How do I set up a Webhook between Azure DevOps and Microsoft Power Automate?

Can you please provide a detailed setup guide on how to setup Web hook between Microsoft flows and Azure DevOps? Including details like:

- If any URL/URI to be provided what kind of URL/URI from where we can get the URI/URL either at Power Automate or at Dev-Ops end.

The idea is to queue a build using Power Automate in DevOps and, when the build is completed, depending on the status of the build, I'll be executing a few other steps in the flow.

Since after queuing the build in DevOps the completion can take time depending on objects to be built and packages to be made (and some other reasons), I want my workflow to wait instead of pinging for the status every now and then.

We thought to use web hook integration between Power Automate and Azure DevOps so that the trigger passes information when the build completes from Azure DevOps to Flow whereupon, depending on the status, other steps can be executed.

We don't want to use delay as sometimes the delay will be more and sometimes less that is why we wanted Webhooks.

We went through blogs such as:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-openapi-definition

But did not get the detailed information as such requested above as we do not know what details are to be provided at the Power Automate end or whether a Power Automate URL is to be provided in the Webhook created at Azure DevOps end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do it:

I created my own service and then through a webhook in Microsoft Power Automate I called this created service with POST method by passing the callbackURL as a parameter.

In the Service POST the callback URL back if the desired result is obtained.

This will make the Power Automate flow continue its execution. Until or unless the callback URL is posted, the flow will be waiting, hence it can go to sleep 'til the desired process is completed. The process can be done through the service you have created; this can be your own REST API.